# jQuery fadein/fadeout ONLY in FF and Opera

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fadein, fadeout

I loaded my site into other browers and the menu fadein/out effect seems to only work in FF and opera. It didnt work in IE(7-9), safari, or chrome. For these browsers it had a show/hide effect instead of fading. here is my [site](http://for-instance.net/).

JS:

```
var delay = 100;
var fade = 400;

$j(function(){
    var inner="";
    $j('#access-navi .sub > a').toggle(function(){
        inner=$j(this).parent().find('ul li');
        inner.each(function(i){
            $j(this).delay(i*delay).fadeIn(fade);
        });
    },function(){
        inner.fadeOut(fade/2);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="access-navi" role="navigation">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Code</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Html.Css</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Java</a></li>
      <li><a href="">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Php</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: IE8 is reporting a javascript error - Message: Invalid property value. Line: 4 Char: 270 Code: 0 URI: http://for-instance.net/wp-content/themes/Starkers/js/script.js?ver=1.0

Comment: I don't see the error in IE8, how did you bring it up?

Comment: the error went away with the update to 1.4.4. With 1.4.2 I had the Error! icon at the bottom left and you click on it to open the error dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not married to jQuery version 1.4.2 then I recommend version 1.4.4. I downloaded your page source, changed the jQuery version to 1.4.4 hosted on the Google CDN and the fade in and out worked locally on my IE8 install.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
```

Comment: also, i tried what you said, IE works now. Chrome/Safari do not still.. I don't know what would cause this issue.

Comment: @Nils R - I just loaded your site in Chrome and the fade in/out is working for me. I saw the updated 1.4.4 in source.

Comment: thats strange.. each element just blinks in for me. Well i mean if it works for you then thats fine. its probably something wrong on my end(computer-related). Thanks